# Canvas shows only one picture(the last) from the list

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas

I'm trying to draw a chessboard by canvas, but I get only one piece at the end of the code. I tried to draw a line and it still exists, but piece no!

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class pawn:
    def __init__(self,coords, color, board):
        self.color = color
        self.board = board
        self.type = "pawn"
        self.x = coords[0]
        self.y = coords[1]
        pass


def draw_board(board):
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=512, height=512)
    canvas.pack()
    for line in range(8):
        for cell in range(8):
            if board[line][cell] != "":
                l = r"C:\python\Chess\images\ "[:-1]
                l = l + board[line][cell].type + board[line][cell].color[0] + ".png"
                print(l)
                img = PhotoImage(file=l)
                canvas.create_image(32 + line*64, 32 + cell*64, image=img)
    root.mainloop()

board = [[""for j in range(8)] for k in range(8)]

pawn_1 = pawn([1,1],"White",board)
pawn_2 = pawn([2,2],"Black",board)
board[2][2] = pawn_1
board[1][1] = pawn_2

draw_board(board)
```

It's working with one piece, but if I create 2 in the list, it'll draw only the last.

Comment: It is because you have used same variable `img` for all the images, so only the last one has variable referencing it and the reset will be garbage collected.

Comment: I used array and it works. Thank you!